# printing more than one page per sheet with raw postscript/IPP/CUPS

Tags: hp, network-printer, cups, printing

we have a raw postscript printer (HP LJP M425dn) that CUPS (1.5.3-5+deb7u1) addresses by IPP with driver "Local Raw Printer (grayscale)". CUPS's own "print test page" produces a sheet with monospaced text starting with "#PDF-BANNER", but thankfully i can print from various applications.

in the GTK (3.4.2-7) print dialog that my firefox, GIMP, and evince use, asking for multiple pages per sheet does nothing. meanwhile, the same in the custom print dialog of libreoffice (3.5.4+dfsg2-0+deb7u2) DOES get the desired effect.

what could be wrong?

Comment: It could simply be LibreOffice itself the generates multipage Layout natively instead of relying on the print driver to do so?

Comment: Using a more appropriate driver might help.

Comment: HBruijn, that's an interesting idea, worth investigating. Michael, i decided to spend more to get a printer that speaks raw postscript because my experiences with both the OSS and closed binary HP drivers didn't pan out. in that PS is among the most general (even turing-complete) printer languages, it does seem to be an appropriate driver.